# Accessing Variable of Bootstrapped Service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to learn how service injection works in Angular 2. I have created an app and a service. My service is as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()

export class UserService {
  logged: boolean;
  users: Array<any>;

  constructor () {
    this.logged = false;
    this.users = [
      {username: 'david', password: 'password'}
    ]
  }

  checkLogin (username, password) {
    this.users.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
        this.logged = true;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.logged = false;
        return false;
      }
    })
  }

  logOut () {
    this.logged = false;
  }
}
```

I am injecting this into the bootstrap so that I can access it throughout the application as follows:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, UserService]);
```

I have then tried to access this in one of my components views but cannot do so. I have tried to access it like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: '<li><a>{{UserService.logged}}</a></li>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class NavbarComponent {
}
```

It does not allow me to access the variable, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the service in your component. In bootstrap you initialized/constructed it (made a *singleton* - meaning one instance for all components), but you have to import and assign it to the component property to be able to use it. Component's template only has access to component's properties and methods...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: '<li><a>{{userService.logged}}</a></li>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class NavbarComponent {
  // this way you let TS declare it
  constructor(public userService: UserService) {}
  // this is same as:
  // userService;
  // constructor(userService: UserService) {
  //   this.userService = userService;
  // }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused with the redeclaring in other examples. I was under the impression that redeclaring it made it non singleton.

Comment: That would happen if you added it to `@Component({ providers: [UserService] })`

Comment: Does that mean I will have to add it to every component that wishes to use the service? Can I access the service of a parent from the child is what I mean.

Comment: You have to import it and add to component's property, yes. But don't add it to the `providers` array.

Comment: @DavidFH, "Can I access the service of a parent from the child" -- in Angular 2, children rarely try to access parent properties.  The notion of scope inheritance and hence shared scope properties is gone.  Parents share data with children via input properties.  Children share data with parents via events.  All other sharing is normally done this way -- with a shared service, that is injected into each component that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Sasxa's answer.  I use this approach when I need to do some other login or logout related actions.

UserService:

```js
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public doLoginUpdate: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  logged: boolean;
  users: Array<any>;

  constructor () {
    this.logged = false;
    this.users = [
      {username: 'david', password: 'password'}
    ]
  }

  checkLogin (username, password) {
    this.users.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
        this.logged = true;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.logged = false;
        return false;
      }
    })
    this.doLoginUpdate.emit(this.logged);
  }

  logOut () {
    this.logged = false;
    this.doLoginUpdate.emit(this.logged);
  }
}
```

NavbarComponent:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: '<li><a>{{logged}}</a></li>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class NavbarComponent {
    logged: boolean = false;
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService) {
        this.userService.doLoginUpdate.subscribe((logged)=>{
            this.logged = logged;
            //do something important related to logging in or logging out


            
        });;
    }
}
```